# vb.net foreign key insert sql statement

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access, join

I have encounter a problem where it tell me I have an Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE','INSERT','PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

I am trying to insert data that use foreign key.

Table pemain contain
*ID
MABOPA
PKBM
MBA
MBEIA
PPPBBM
MAPIM*

Table Ahli contain
*ID
company_name
name
address
poscode 
state
email
phone
fax
company_reg
website
remarks
pemain*

where field pemain in table Ahli is the foreign key of table pemain

the code im using are

```
    Dim Pos As Integer
    Dim Pemain As Integer

    Int32.TryParse(TxtBoxPoscode.Text, Pos)
    Int32.TryParse(TxtBoxPemainId.Text, Pemain)

    Access.AddParam("@MABOPA", TextBox1.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@PKBM", TextBox2.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@MBA", TextBox3.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@MBEIA", TextBox4.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@PPPBBM", TextBox5.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@MAPIM", TextBox6.Text)

    Access.AddParam("@companyname", TxtBoxComName.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@name", TxtBoxName.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@address", TxtBoxAdd.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@poscode", Pos)
    Access.AddParam("@state", CboBoxState.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@email", TxtBoxEmail.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@phone", TxtBoxPhone.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@fax", TxtBoxFax.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@companyreg", TxtBoxComName.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@web", TxtBoxWebsite.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@remarks", TxtBoxRemarks.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@pemain", Pemain)

    'Execute Insert Command

                  Access.ExecQuery(
                 "START TRANSACTION;" & _
                 "INSERT INTO pemain (MABOPA, PKBM, MBA, MBEIA, PPPBBM, MAPIM);" & _
                 "VALUES (@MABOPA, @PKBM, @MBA, @MBEIA, @PPPBBM, @MAPIM);" & _
                 "DECLARE @NewID INT;" & _
                 "SELECT @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();" & _
                 "INSERT INTO Ahli (company_name, name, address, poscode, state, email, phone, fax, company_reg, website, remarks, pemain);" & _
                 "VALUES (@companyname, @name, @address, @poscode, @state, @email, @phone, @fax, @companyreg, @web, @remarks, @NewID);" & _
                 "COMMIT;")
```

It would be a really great if anyone could help me.

Comment: Your code is T-SQL and is far away from what Access SQL understands. You will have to rewrite this completely using Access SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the Jet nor ACE OLE DB providers support multiple SQL statements per command.  If you want to execute multiple SQL statements then you must execute multiple commands (or the same command more than once with different SQL statements) and if you want to wrap them in a transaction then you call `BeginTransaction` on your `OleDbConnection` to create an `OleDbTransaction`.

By the way, I'm not sure that `SCOPE_IDENTITY` exists in Access.  I could be wrong but I think that that's specific to SQL Server.  I think Access requires using `@@IDENTITY`.

Comment: Yep, `Access` uses `@@IDENTITY`. The whole query needs writing to be honest, `Access` will quake in dear trying to work out what to do with that!